# Probability distribution of shooting a target

Tags: probability

So I have a problem with this situation. I calculated probability distribution and it does not sum to $1$.

We have 5 balls. Target is destroyed after we shoot it 3 times. Probability of scoring is 0.8. Situations ends if we destroy our target or we run out of balls.

$X$ is the number of shots.

$P(X) = P(X \leq 5) + P (X \leq 4) + P(X \leq 3)$

$ P(X \leq 5)= 0.2^2 \times 0.8^3 + 0.2^3\times0.8^2 + 0.2^4\times0.8 + 0.2^5 = 0.272 $
$ P(X \leq 4)= 0.2\times0.8^3 + 0.2^2\times0.8^2 + 0.2^3\times0.8 + 0.2^4 = 0.136 $
$ P(X \leq 3)= 0.8^3 + 0.2\times0.8^2 + 0.2^2\times0.8 + 0.2^3  = 0.68 $

It's sum is $1.088$ not $1$.

I don't know where I made a mistake.

Comment: $\Pr(X=3)=(0.8)^3$. For $X=4$, want two hits in first three, then a hit. Probability $\binom{3}{2}(0.8)^2(0.2)(0.8)$. You can do $\Pr(X=5)$.

Comment: So $ Pr(X=5) it's \binom{3}{2}(0.8)^2(0.2)(0.2)(0.8) $ And the score is again not 1.

Comment: It is $\binom{4}{2}$ not $\binom{3}{2}$.

Comment: Ok. My bad. But the sum of this 3 probabilities is 0.94 not 1.

Comment: I will write an answer. It may take a while, busy day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume that the results of the shots are independent. Let random variable $X$ be the number of shots taken.

We have $X=3$ if our first three shots land. This has probability $(0.8)^3$.

We have $X=4$ if exactly $2$ of the first three shots land, and then the fourth lands. The probability of this is $\binom{3}{2}(0.8)^2(0.2)(0.8)$.

The case $X=5$ is more complicated, for beside the possibility that the target is destroyed on the fifth shot, there are also the cases where we run out of balls without destroying the target. The simplest way to find $\Pr(X=5)$ is to calculate $1-\Pr(X=3)-\Pr(X=4)$.

But there are other ways. For example, we have $X=5$ precisely if $0$ or $1$ or $2$ of the **first four** shots land. This has probability
$$(0.2)^4+\binom{4}{1}(0.8)(0.2)^3 +\binom{4}{2}(0.8)^2(0.2)^2.$$

Comment: Ok. In the last addition is (0.8)^2(0.8)^2. It should be (0.8)^2(0.2)^2. Now it sums to 1.

Comment: @davoid: Thanks for spotting it.